# Optimize performance for finding ranges in tibble/data.frame

Tags: r

I have the following dataset (more than 30.000 rows in reality):

```
dt <- tibble::tibble(x=seq.Date(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-10"), "days"), y=c(1,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,2,1))

A tibble: 10 x 2
   x              y
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2019-01-01     1
 2 2019-01-02     2
 3 2019-01-03     3
 4 2019-01-04     2
 5 2019-01-05     1
 6 2019-01-06     1
 7 2019-01-07     3
 8 2019-01-08     1
 9 2019-01-09     2
10 2019-01-10     1
```

I would like to identify date-ranges above a given threshold, for example y >= 2. The first date of appearance of the range should be saved in a separate tibble as "start", the last date of appearance as "end". Each "start"/"end"-combination should be saved in a separate line. The ranges are separated from each other by "y"-values that are below the threshold (e.g. y < 2). The result should look like the following table:

```
result <- tibble::tibble(start=as.Date(c("2019-01-02", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-09")), end=as.Date(c("2019-01-04", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-09")))

A tibble: 3 x 2
   start      end       
   <date>     <date>    
 1 2019-01-02 2019-01-04
 2 2019-01-07 2019-01-07
 3 2019-01-09 2019-01-09
```

My current solution is using for-loops. However, this leads to very slow execution.

**Any ideas how to improve the performance and solve this issue more elegant?**

Thank you for your ideas in advance.

Comment: Please check your expected output. It is not clear why you are removing the 3rd row, where y is 3

Comment: The output is correct. Only the start and end date should be saved. A range ends when the value falls below the threshold.

Comment: If we filter by the condition, you get `dt %>% filter(y >=2)` five rows.  From there, it is not clear why the row 2 is deleted

Comment: Because the row is part of the first range and therefore between "2019-01-02" and "2019-01-04". That makes it tricky, as I can’t detect the ranges based on filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work and is based on the idea that the diff of the dates minus 1 will have a cumulative sum equal to each other. That's why we can group by it.

```
dt%>%
  filter(y >= 2)%>%
  group_by(grouping = cumsum(c(0, diff.Date(x) - 1)))%>%
  summarize(start = min(x)
            , end = max(x))%>%
  select(-grouping)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  start      end       
  <date>     <date>    
1 2019-01-02 2019-01-04
2 2019-01-07 2019-01-07
3 2019-01-09 2019-01-09
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that identifies groups of consecutive values of a vector statisfing a condition

```
f = function(x, min) {
    ## 'run length encoding' of values satisfying the condition
    r = rle(x > min)
    ## replace TRUE values with a grouping variable; FALSE values are coerced to 0
    ## (probably better to also replace r$values[!r$values] = NA)
    r$values[r$values] = seq_len(sum(r$values))
    ## expand the modified run length encoding to the shape of the original vector
    inverse.rle(r)
}
```

For your data, we have

```
> mutate(dt, grp = f(y, 1))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   x              y   grp
   <date>     <dbl> <int>
 1 2019-01-01     1     0
 2 2019-01-02     2     1
 3 2019-01-03     3     1
 4 2019-01-04     2     1
 5 2019-01-05     1     0
 6 2019-01-06     1     0
 7 2019-01-07     3     2
 8 2019-01-08     1     0
 9 2019-01-09     2     3
10 2019-01-10     1     0
```

and we can then use standard dplyr operations

```
mutate(dt, grp = f(y, 1)) %>% 
    filter(grp != 0) %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarize(start = min(x), end = max(x), n = n())
```

with the output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
    grp start      end            n
  <int> <date>     <date>     <int>
1     1 2019-01-02 2019-01-04     3
2     2 2019-01-07 2019-01-07     1
3     3 2019-01-09 2019-01-09     1
```